# Android App Icon Alert

Tags: android, icons, alert

is there a way to change the app icon dynamically. In the sense, my app's basic functionality is to show the user, any generated reports. What i want to be able to do is change my app icon dyanamically to show a red circle at the top of my app icon in the tray whenever a report is generated. Similiar to alert cicles at the top of inbox icons in adroid phones whenever a new message arrives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately now: the icon is hardcoded in the AndroidManifest file. It was designed this way, so the app icon can be retrieved without running any piece of code (which would result in slower startup time for the launcher application)

Some custom home applications support this, but with private APIs.

You can try to use the NotificationManager and add an icon to the status bar. That would be even more visible.

Comment: This is actually the recommended way of doing it. You should really use the status bar in such cases, that is what it's designed for :-)